# progress bar and multiple download

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progress-bar

i want to download multiple file(2 for the moment) in one progress bar(without reseting the progress bar)

In order to do this , i retrieve the total lenght of all file in order to use it in the publish progress method

The problem is that my progress bar reset to 0 once reached 50% then increment again until another 50%

Here is my code

```
@Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            int totalSizeFile;
            totalSizeFile=cm.getLength(url[0]);
            totalSizeFile+=cm.getLength(url[1]);
            progressBar.setMax(totalSizeFile);

            cm.downloadMp3(url[0], "test.mp3", totalTailleFic);
            cm.downloadMp3(url[1], "test2.mp3", totalTailleFic);


            return null;            

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

            textview.setText(String.valueOf(progress[0])+"%");
            progressBar.incrementProgressBy(progress[0]);


        }
```

The code of my download function where i call the publishprogress method

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bufferLength = 0;
            int total=0;
            while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            total += bufferLength;
            fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);

            asynch.publishProgress(bufferLength);

            }
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ProgressBar` resets to zero between downloads because the variable `total` also resets to zero.

In order to keep track of the current progress, the progress bar will have to increment with `progressBar.incrementProgressBy()` instead of setting the value with `progressBar.setProgress()`.

This means that the `publishProgress()` and `onProgressUpdate()` methods will also have to be modified to process `increment` instead of `progress`. And, the increment is your `bufferLength`:

```
asynch.publishProgress(bufferLength);
```

You will also have to initialize your `ProgressBar` with the total number of bytes for the sum of both downloads with `progressBar.setMax()`.

Comment: Hello. Thank u for your help , but if i try incrementProgressBy , now my progress bar fills at once without chunks

Comment: But indeed the progress variable of OnProgressUpdate reset to 0 between each download.

Comment: Use `setMax()` to initialize the `ProgressBar` with the total number of bytes (see edit).

Comment: It doesn't matter what you put on the `Progress` parameters of `OnProgressUpdate()`. It can be actual progress, increment, or even just indicate a single step. Just take that value and treat it like an *increment* and send it to `incrementProgressBy()`.

Comment: Thank you . I update my code but i can't even see the progress bar increase now .

Comment: Sorry but i don 't understand your last reply . What do you mean ? Thank you very much

Comment: Ok, if the `setMax()` sets the total number of bytes, then each call to `asynch.publishProgress(bufferLength)` must send `bufferLength` because the number of bytes read each time is now the increment.

Comment: Thank you very much , it works great now , but it is possible to do the same work with percentage ? Because i have a text view which show the progression in percentage. Bufferlength can t work with percentage

Comment: I think your solution is good when we have only a progress bar to display . But if we need indicator , we need to fill progress bar with percentage

Comment: But, of course we need percentage. This solution provides smooth progress. You calculated the total number of bytes. You set the `ProgressBar` max to the total bytes. Every time you get a chunk of data from either download, you send the chunk size to the `ProgressBar` as an incremental update. When the 2nd download completes, the `ProgressBar` will be at 100%.

Comment: OK i understand . Thank you very much for taking your time to help me . I really appreciate your help.